# ui-router infinite loop with redirect

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to restrict a few pages to authenticated users only and what I'm doing so far is:

```
  // 
  // Application Routes
  // -----------------------------------   
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/core.client.view.html'
    })
    .state('app.home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html',
      data: { requiresLogin: true }
    });
```

And:

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'Authentication', function ($rootScope, $state, Authentication) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
    var isAuthenticationRequired = toState.data && toState.data.requiresLogin && !Authentication.user;

    if (isAuthenticationRequired) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('page.signin');
    }
  });
}]);
```

It should be a simple thing to do but it isn't... It restrict the page but what I receive is:

```
`Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

And my server side console log spam hundreds of `GET` to my `'/signin'` page...
`event.preventDefault()` do nothing here?

How can I just redirect without this infinite loop?

Comment: btw, I suggest you this way of handling authentication with ui-router : http://www.jvandemo.com/learn-how-to-make-authentication-in-your-angular-applications-simpler-and-more-consistent/

Comment: Sorry but I'm not so idiot... I didn't pasted the entire project... it is in another file.

Comment: I don't need to rebuild an entire authentication, the one I have is working fine, I just need now to create a simple redirect if `!Authentication.user`...

Comment: just an idea.. try to set  ´ isAuthenticationRequired ´ to FALSE   inside the IF contidion ´if (isAuthenticationRequired) {isAuthenticationRequired = false; event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('page.signin');
    }´

Comment: If I move it out from the `.run` and I put it in the core controller I do not receive the error anymore... it's just weird.